# In WPF is the UI dispatcher.begininvoke method thread safe?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF app that makes use of some multi threading.  I am curious to know if calling into the UI thread by using the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method considered thread-safe?  Normally i would use the lock statement to make sure only one thread can access a variable.  Would the following be thread-safe in a WPF app?

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    _counter ++;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) will run its callback on the Dispatcher thread (typcially the UI thread, unless you have multiple Dispatchers)

Therefore, if you only use the `counter` variable on the UI thread, you will have no threading issues.